# JSON to CSV Complex Structure

Tags: powershell

I have written the below code for conversion of JSON to CSV. However for the tag LineItems it does not generate the correct structure.

Code below :

```
$src = "C:\Users\sneshah\Desktop\unzip\OutputFile\"
$outputFile = "C:\Users\sneshah\Desktop\unzip\csv\"    
$foldername = Get-ChildItem $src -Filter *
foreach($files in $foldername)
{
$newfoldername = $src + $files + "\records.txt"

$pathToOutputFile = $outputFile + $files + ".csv"
((Get-Content -Path $newfoldername) | ConvertFrom-Json) |
ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
Set-Content $pathToOutputFile

$removeconvertedfolder = $src + $files 

Remove-Item -Path $removeconvertedfolder -Recurse

}
```

Please excuse for this huge post, the JSON is extensive, I have just extracted one record and pasted it here.

JSON Structure :

```
[{"IsNonPO":false,"ApprovedState":4,"ApprovalRecords":null,"InitialUniqueName":"INVINV499-1436","SubmitDate":"2018-03-07T15:47:53Z","HoldTillDate":null,"SupplierLocation":{"UniqueName":"AD167689670"},"CreateDate":"2018-03-07T15:41:19Z","RemitToAddress":null,"Name":"INVINV499-1436","LastModified":"2018-03-07T15:48:12Z","TotalCost":{"AmountInReportingCurrency":10.2000000000,"ApproxAmountInBaseCurrency":10.2000000000,"Amount":10.2000000000,"ConversionDate":"2018-03-07T15:46:42Z","Currency":{"UniqueName":"USD"}},"TimeCreated":"2018-03-07T15:47:53Z","TaxAmount":null,"Requester":{"UniqueName":"kokrishna","PasswordAdapter":"PasswordAdapter1"},"TaxDetails":null,"VATAmount":null,"TotalInvoicedLessTax":{"AmountInReportingCurrency":10.0000000000,"ApproxAmountInBaseCurrency":10.0000000000,"Amount":10.0000000000,"ConversionDate":"2018-03-07T15:47:18Z","Currency":{"UniqueName":"USD"}},"RemitToID":null,"InvoiceNumber":"INV499","Order":{"UniqueName":"PO499"},"LineItems":[{"Description.CommonCommodityCode":null,"TaxDetail.FormulaString":null,"TaxDetail.IsDeductible":null,"OriginalPrice":null,"InvoiceLineNumber":1,"ExpectedTax.TaxRate":null,"ExpectedTax.TaxCode":null,"NumberConfirmedAccepted":0E-10,"ChargeAmount":null,"SplitAccountings":[{"PONumber":"","ERPSplitValue":"","WBSElement":null,"Percentage":100.0000000000,"Amount":{"AmountInReportingCurrency":10.0000000000,"ApproxAmountInBaseCurrency":10.0000000000,"Amount":10.0000000000,"ConversionDate":"2018-03-07T15:45:39Z","Currency":{"UniqueName":"USD"}},"Quantity":1.0000000000,"InternalOrder":null,"NumberInCollection":1,"Type":{"UniqueName":"_Percentage"},"ProcurementUnit":null,"CostCenter":null,"POLineNumber":"","GeneralLedger":null,"Asset":null,"CompanyCode":null}],"TaxAmount":{"AmountInReportingCurrency":0.2000000000,"ApproxAmountInBaseCurrency":0.2000000000,"Amount":0.2000000000,"ConversionDate":"2018-03-07T15:48:45Z","Currency":{"UniqueName":"USD"}},"ExpectedTax.IsAccrual":null,"TaxDetail.Category":null,"VATAmount":null,"ChargeDetail.ANChargeDescription":null,"Description.IndexContractPrice":null,"ServiceDetails.RequiresServiceEntry":false,"Description.Language":"","TaxDetail.Percent":null,"TaxDetail.PerUnit":null,"ShipFrom":{"State":"CA","Phone":"","Country":{"UniqueName":"US"},"PostalCode":"94203","City":"Sacramento","Fax":"","UniqueName":"AD170035991","Lines":"Deloitte Towers","Name":"DAA LE Supplier-TEST"},"DueOn":null,"Description.SupplierURL":"","DiscountAmount":null,"ServicePeriod":{"Period":"Custom","FromDate":"2018-03-06T08:00:00Z","ToDate":"2018-03-08T07:59:59Z"},"ServiceDetails.ServiceEndDate":null,"ExpectedTax.TaxableAmount":null,"ChargeDetail.ChargeAmount":null,"ServiceDetails.ExpectedAmount":null,"Description.UnitOfMeasure":{"UniqueName":"HUR"},"Description.NonContractPrice":null,"ChargeDetail.ANChargeName":null,"Description.LineItem":{"NumberInCollection":1,"InvoiceLineNumber":1},"TaxDetail.AbatementPercent":null,"MasterAgreement":null,"Description.ContractPrice":null,"IsAdHoc":true,"NumberConfirmedAcceptedWithChanges":0E-10,"BillingAddress":{"State":"CA","Phone":"","Country":{"UniqueName":"US"},"PostalCode":"94304","City":"Palo Alto","Fax":"","UniqueName":"ZH10","Lines":"3475 Deer Creek","Name":"Hi Tech US Manufacturing Plant"},"NumberInCollection":1,"NumberShipped":0E-10,"Description.ExtAttributesBitMask":0,"CommodityCode":null,"Description.ShortName":"","Supplier":{"UniqueName":"DAA LE Supplier","Name":"DAA LE Supplier"},"Description.PriceBasisQuantityDesc":null,"ServiceDetails.MaxAmount":null,"Description.ConversionFactor":null,"DeliverTo":"Komal Krishna","Description.KitUniqueName":null,"CarrierMethod":"","TaxDetail.TaxableAmount":null,"Amount":{"AmountInReportingCurrency":10.0000000000,"ApproxAmountInBaseCurrency":10.0000000000,"Amount":10.0000000000,"ConversionDate":"2018-03-07T15:45:39Z","Currency":{"UniqueName":"USD"}},"EndDate":null,"ServiceDetails.ServiceLine":true,"GRBasedInvoice":false,"OrderLineItem":null,"Description.CustomPrice":null,"ServiceDetails.ServiceStartDate":null,"ShipTo":{"State":"CA","Phone":"","Country":{"UniqueName":"US"},"PostalCode":"94304","City":"Palo Alto","Fax":"","UniqueName":"ZH10","Lines":"3475 Deer Creek","Name":"Hi Tech US Manufacturing Plant"},"SupplierOrderInfo":{"MANumber":"","OrderNumber":"PO499","ReceiptNumber":""},"ItemMasterID":null,"ReferenceDate":"2018-03-07T10:30:43Z","Description.QueryID":"","Description.PriceBasisQuantity":null,"TaxDetail.Description":null,"BasePrice":null,"Description.SupplierPartAuxiliaryID":"","ExpectedTax.Component":null,"InspectionDate":null,"IsPriceModifiedByUser":false,"ChargeDetail.TaxAmount":null,"Description.ExtendedDescription":"","SupplierLocation":{"UniqueName":"AD167689670"},"TaxDetail.TaxLocation":null,"TaxDetail.TaxAmount":null,"StartDate":null,"TaxDetail.ExemptDetail":null,"Description.Description":"Test","IsRecurring":false,"NumberConfirmedSubstituted":0E-10,"TaxDetail.AlternateTaxAmount":null,"Description.ExpirationDate":null,"Carrier":"","Description.SupplierPartNumber":"","TaxDetail.PaymentDate":null,"Order":{"UniqueName":"PO499"},"NumberConfirmedBackOrdered":0E-10,"ChargeDetail.TaxCode":null,"Description.LeadTime":0,"ERPLineItemNumber":"","Description.PriceBasisQuantityUOM":null,"Description.ItemNumber":"","Category":1,"ChargeDetail.ChargeType":null,"NumberConfirmedRejected":0E-10,"PaymentTerms":null,"TaxCode":null,"LineType":{"UniqueName":"_NonCatalogItem"},"Description.Price":{"AmountInReportingCurrency":10.0000000000,"ApproxAmountInBaseCurrency":10.0000000000,"Amount":10.0000000000,"ConversionDate":"2018-03-07T15:45:39Z","Currency":{"UniqueName":"USD"}},"TaxDetail.TaxPointDate":null,"OrderLineNumber":0,"WithholdingTaxAmount":null,"TaxDetail.Component":null,"BoughtFromPreferredSupplier":false,"Quantity":1.0000000000,"TaxDetail.Purpose":null,"OrderInfo":null,"TaxDetail.IsTriangularTransaction":null,"ExpectedTax.TaxType":null,"MALineItem":null,"TaxDetail.TriangularTransactionLawReference":null},{"Description.CommonCommodityCode":null,"TaxDetail.FormulaString":"","TaxDetail.IsDeductible":false,"OriginalPrice":null,"InvoiceLineNumber":1,"ExpectedTax.TaxRate":0E-10,"ExpectedTax.TaxCode":null,"NumberConfirmedAccepted":0E-10,"ChargeAmount":null,"SplitAccountings":[{"PONumber":"","ERPSplitValue":"","WBSElement":null,"Percentage":100.0000000000,"Amount":{"AmountInReportingCurrency":0.2000000000,"ApproxAmountInBaseCurrency":0.2000000000,"Amount":0.2000000000,"ConversionDate":"2018-03-07T15:46:41Z","Currency":{"UniqueName":"USD"}},"Quantity":1.0000000000,"InternalOrder":null,"NumberInCollection":1,"Type":{"UniqueName":"_Percentage"},"ProcurementUnit":null,"CostCenter":null,"POLineNumber":"","GeneralLedger":null,"Asset":null,"CompanyCode":null}],"TaxAmount":null,"ExpectedTax.IsAccrual":false,"TaxDetail.Category":"sales","VATAmount":null,"ChargeDetail.ANChargeDescription":null,"Description.IndexContractPrice":null,"ServiceDetails.RequiresServiceEntry":null,"Description.Language":"en","TaxDetail.Percent":2.0000000000,"TaxDetail.PerUnit":0E-10,"ShipFrom":{"State":"CA","Phone":"","Country":{"UniqueName":"US"},"PostalCode":"94203","City":"Sacramento","Fax":"","UniqueName":"AD170035991","Lines":"Deloitte Towers","Name":"DAA LE Supplier-TEST"},"DueOn":null,"Description.SupplierURL":"","DiscountAmount":null,"ServicePeriod":null,"ServiceDetails.ServiceEndDate":null,"ExpectedTax.TaxableAmount":null,"ChargeDetail.ChargeAmount":null,"ServiceDetails.ExpectedAmount":null,"Description.UnitOfMeasure":null,"Description.NonContractPrice":null,"ChargeDetail.ANChargeName":null,"Description.LineItem":{"NumberInCollection":2,"InvoiceLineNumber":1},"TaxDetail.AbatementPercent":0E-10,"MasterAgreement":null,"Description.ContractPrice":null,"IsAdHoc":true,"NumberConfirmedAcceptedWithChanges":0E-10,"BillingAddress":{"State":"CA","Phone":"","Country":{"UniqueName":"US"},"PostalCode":"94304","City":"Palo Alto","Fax":"","UniqueName":"ZH10","Lines":"3475 Deer Creek","Name":"Hi Tech US Manufacturing Plant"},"NumberInCollection":2,"NumberShipped":0E-10,"Description.ExtAttributesBitMask":0,"CommodityCode":null,"Description.ShortName":"","Supplier":{"UniqueName":"DAA LE Supplier","Name":"DAA LE Supplier"},"Description.PriceBasisQuantityDesc":null,"ServiceDetails.MaxAmount":null,"Description.ConversionFactor":null,"DeliverTo":"Komal Krishna","Description.KitUniqueName":null,"CarrierMethod":"","TaxDetail.TaxableAmount":{"AmountInReportingCurrency":10.0000000000,"ApproxAmountInBaseCurrency":10.0000000000,"Amount":10.0000000000,"ConversionDate":"2018-03-07T15:46:41Z","Currency":{"UniqueName":"USD"}},"Amount":{"AmountInReportingCurrency":0.2000000000,"ApproxAmountInBaseCurrency":0.2000000000,"Amount":0.2000000000,"ConversionDate":"2018-03-07T15:46:41Z","Currency":{"UniqueName":"USD"}},"EndDate":null,"ServiceDetails.ServiceLine":null,"GRBasedInvoice":false,"OrderLineItem":null,"Description.CustomPrice":null,"ServiceDetails.ServiceStartDate":null,"ShipTo":{"State":"CA","Phone":"","Country":{"UniqueName":"US"},"PostalCode":"94304","City":"Palo Alto","Fax":"","UniqueName":"ZH10","Lines":"3475 Deer Creek","Name":"Hi Tech US Manufacturing Plant"},"SupplierOrderInfo":{"MANumber":"","OrderNumber":"PO499","ReceiptNumber":""},"ItemMasterID":null,"ReferenceDate":"2018-03-07T10:30:43Z","Description.QueryID":"","Description.PriceBasisQuantity":null,"TaxDetail.Description":"Tax","BasePrice":null,"Description.SupplierPartAuxiliaryID":"","ExpectedTax.Component":null,"InspectionDate":null,"IsPriceModifiedByUser":false,"ChargeDetail.TaxAmount":null,"Description.ExtendedDescription":"","SupplierLocation":{"UniqueName":"AD167689670"},"TaxDetail.TaxLocation":"","TaxDetail.TaxAmount":{"AmountInReportingCurrency":0.2000000000,"ApproxAmountInBaseCurrency":0.2000000000,"Amount":0.2000000000,"ConversionDate":"2018-03-07T15:46:41Z","Currency":{"UniqueName":"USD"}},"StartDate":null,"TaxDetail.ExemptDetail":"","Description.Description":"Tax","IsRecurring":false,"NumberConfirmedSubstituted":0E-10,"TaxDetail.AlternateTaxAmount":{"AmountInReportingCurrency":0.2000000000,"ApproxAmountInBaseCurrency":0.2000000000,"Amount":0.2000000000,"ConversionDate":"2018-03-07T15:46:41Z","Currency":{"UniqueName":"USD"}},"Description.ExpirationDate":null,"Carrier":"","Description.SupplierPartNumber":"","TaxDetail.PaymentDate":null,"Order":{"UniqueName":"PO499"},"NumberConfirmedBackOrdered":0E-10,"ChargeDetail.TaxCode":null,"Description.LeadTime":0,"ERPLineItemNumber":"","Description.PriceBasisQuantityUOM":null,"Description.ItemNumber":"","Category":1,"ChargeDetail.ChargeType":null,"NumberConfirmedRejected":0E-10,"PaymentTerms":null,"TaxCode":null,"LineType":{"UniqueName":"SalesTax"},"Description.Price":{"AmountInReportingCurrency":0.2000000000,"ApproxAmountInBaseCurrency":0.2000000000,"Amount":0.2000000000,"ConversionDate":"2018-03-07T15:46:41Z","Currency":{"UniqueName":"USD"}},"TaxDetail.TaxPointDate":null,"OrderLineNumber":0,"WithholdingTaxAmount":null,"TaxDetail.Component":null,"BoughtFromPreferredSupplier":false,"Quantity":1.0000000000,"TaxDetail.Purpose":"","OrderInfo":null,"TaxDetail.IsTriangularTransaction":false,"ExpectedTax.TaxType":{"UniqueName":"SalesTax"},"MALineItem":null,"TaxDetail.TriangularTransactionLawReference":""}],"ChangedBy":null,"ApprovedDate":"2018-03-07T15:48:10Z","InvoiceOrigin":"supplier","TotalWithholdingTax":{"AmountInReportingCurrency":0E-10,"ApproxAmountInBaseCurrency":0E-10,"Amount":0E-10,"ConversionDate":"2018-03-07T15:47:18Z","Currency":{"UniqueName":"USD"}},"Signed":false,"ScheduledPaymentDate":"2018-03-27T09:30:43Z","PreviousApprovalRequestsVersion":-1,"ResubmitDate":null,"PurchaseOrg":{"UniqueName":"ZH01"},"MaxDiscountApplicable":{"AmountInReportingCurrency":0.3000000000,"ApproxAmountInBaseCurrency":0.3000000000,"Amount":0.3000000000,"ConversionDate":"2018-03-07T15:48:45Z","Currency":{"UniqueName":"USD"}},"ServicePeriod":null,"IsTaxInLine":true,"ApprovalRequests":null,"Active":true,"InvoiceSourceDocument":"PurchaseOrder","InvoiceStatusString":"Reconciled","NextVersion":null,"TaxExchangeRate":0E-10,"HeaderLevel":false,"UniqueName":"INVINV499-1436","TotalInvoiced":{"AmountInReportingCurrency":10.2000000000,"ApproxAmountInBaseCurrency":10.2000000000,"Amount":10.2000000000,"ConversionDate":"2018-03-07T15:47:18Z","Currency":{"UniqueName":"USD"}},"Category":1,"MasterAgreement":null,"InvoiceSubmissionMethod":"Online","InvoicePurpose":"standard","PaymentTerms":{"UniqueName":"PT1"},"ReconciledDate":"2018-03-07T16:05:41Z","AccountReceivableID":"","ServiceLocation":null,"TotalTax":{"AmountInReportingCurrency":0.2000000000,"ApproxAmountInBaseCurrency":0.2000000000,"Amount":0.2000000000,"ConversionDate":"2018-03-07T15:47:18Z","Currency":{"UniqueName":"USD"}},"Supplier":{"UniqueName":"DAA LE Supplier","Name":"DAA LE Supplier"},"InvoiceDate":"2018-03-07T10:30:43Z","StatusString":"Reconciled","PreviousVersion":null,"ApprovalRequestsVersion":1,"UpperCaseInvoiceNumber":"INV499","TimeUpdated":"2019-08-22T10:20:31Z","VersionNumber":1,"Type":"ariba.invoicing.core.Invoice","InvoiceOriginType":0,"SupplierName":"","Attachments.Attachments":null,"InvoiceState":4,"SoldTo":{"Address":{"State":"NC","Phone":"","Country":{"UniqueName":"US"},"PostalCode":"28202-4200","City":"Charlotte","Fax":"","UniqueName":"AD86365369","Lines":"550 S. Tryon Street\nSuite 2500","Name":"Deloitte Consulting - TEST"},"Name":""},"CompanyCode":{"UniqueName":"ZH01"},"Preparer":{"UniqueName":"aribasystem","PasswordAdapter":"PasswordAdapter1"},"InvoiceToCredit":null}]
```

The expected sequence in the csv file for lineItems would be

```
LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/WBSElement/CompanyCodeUniqueNameList,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/WBSElement/Description,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/WBSElement/UniqueName,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/WBSElement/ProjectNumber,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/Amount/AmountInReportingCurrency,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/Amount/ApproxAmountInBaseCurrency,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/Amount/Amount,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/Amount/ConversionDate,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/Amount/Currency/UniqueName,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/Quantity,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/InternalOrder,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/NumberInCollection,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/Type/UniqueName,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/ProcurementUnit,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/CostCenter/ProcurementUnit,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/CostCenter/UniqueName,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/CostCenter/CompanyCode/UniqueName,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/CostCenter/CostCenterDescription,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/POLineNumber,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/GeneralLedger/GeneralLedgerDescription,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/GeneralLedger/GeneralLedgerDescription2,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/GeneralLedger/UniqueName,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/GeneralLedger/CompanyCode/UniqueName,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/GeneralLedger/FieldStatusGroup,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/GeneralLedger/ExternalId,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/Asset,LineItems/0/SplitAccountings/0/CompanyCode,LineItems/0/TaxAmount,LineItems/0/ExpectedTax.IsAccrual,LineItems/0/TaxDetail.Category,LineItems/0/VATAmount,LineItems/0/ChargeDetail.ANChargeDescription,LineItems/0/Description.IndexContractPrice,LineItems/0/ServiceDetails.RequiresServiceEntry,LineItems/0/Description.Language,LineItems/0/TaxDetail.Percent,LineItems/0/TaxDetail.PerUnit,LineItems/0/ShipFrom/State,LineItems/0/ShipFrom/Phone,LineItems/0/ShipFrom/Country/UniqueName,LineItems/0/ShipFrom/PostalCode,LineItems/0/ShipFrom/City,LineItems/0/ShipFrom/Fax,LineItems/0/ShipFrom/UniqueName,LineItems/0/ShipFrom/Lines,LineItems/0/ShipFrom/Name,LineItems/0/DueOn,LineItems/0/Description.SupplierURL,LineItems/0/DiscountAmount,LineItems/0/ServicePeriod,LineItems/0/ServiceDetails.ServiceEndDate,LineItems/0/ExpectedTax.TaxableAmount,LineItems/0/ChargeDetail.ChargeAmount,LineItems/0/ServiceDetails.ExpectedAmount,LineItems/0/Description.UnitOfMeasure/UniqueName,LineItems/0/Description.NonContractPrice,LineItems/0/ChargeDetail.ANChargeName,LineItems/0/Description.LineItem/NumberInCollection,LineItems/0/TaxDetail.AbatementPercent,LineItems/0/MasterAgreement/UniqueName,LineItems/0/Description.ContractPrice,LineItems/0/IsAdHoc,LineItems/0/NumberConfirmedAcceptedWithChanges,LineItems/0/BillingAddress/State,LineItems/0/BillingAddress/Phone,LineItems/0/BillingAddress/Country/UniqueName,LineItems/0/BillingAddress/PostalCode,LineItems/0/BillingAddress/City,LineItems/0/BillingAddress/Fax,LineItems/0/BillingAddress/UniqueName,LineItems/0/BillingAddress/Lines,LineItems/0/BillingAddress/Name,LineItems/0/NumberInCollection,LineItems/0/NumberShipped,LineItems/0/Description.ExtAttributesBitMask,LineItems/0/CommodityCode/UniqueName,LineItems/0/Description.ShortName,LineItems/0/Supplier/UniqueName,LineItems/0/Supplier/Name,LineItems/0/Description.PriceBasisQuantityDesc,LineItems/0/ServiceDetails.MaxAmount,LineItems/0/Description.ConversionFactor,LineItems/0/DeliverTo,LineItems/0/Description.KitUniqueName,LineItems/0/CarrierMethod,LineItems/0/TaxDetail.TaxableAmount,LineItems/0/Amount/AmountInReportingCurrency,LineItems/0/Amount/ApproxAmountInBaseCurrency,LineItems/0/Amount/Amount,LineItems/0/Amount/ConversionDate,LineItems/0/Amount/Currency/UniqueName,LineItems/0/EndDate,LineItems/0/ServiceDetails.ServiceLine,LineItems/0/GRBasedInvoice,LineItems/0/OrderLineItem/NumberInCollection,LineItems/0/Description.CustomPrice/AmountInReportingCurrency,LineItems/0/Description.CustomPrice/ApproxAmountInBaseCurrency,LineItems/0/Description.CustomPrice/Amount,LineItems/0/Description.CustomPrice/ConversionDate,LineItems/0/Description.CustomPrice/Currency/UniqueName,LineItems/0/ServiceDetails.ServiceStartDate,LineItems/0/ShipTo/State,LineItems/0/ShipTo/Phone,LineItems/0/ShipTo/Country/UniqueName,LineItems/0/ShipTo/PostalCode,LineItems/0/ShipTo/City,LineItems/0/ShipTo/Fax,LineItems/0/ShipTo/UniqueName,LineItems/0/ShipTo/Lines,LineItems/0/ShipTo/Name,LineItems/0/SupplierOrderInfo/MANumber,LineItems/0/SupplierOrderInfo/OrderNumber,LineItems/0/SupplierOrderInfo/ReceiptNumber,LineItems/0/ItemMasterID,LineItems/0/ReferenceDate,LineItems/0/Description.QueryID,LineItems/0/Description.PriceBasisQuantity,LineItems/0/TaxDetail.Description,LineItems/0/BasePrice/AmountInReportingCurrency,LineItems/0/BasePrice/ApproxAmountInBaseCurrency,LineItems/0/BasePrice/Amount,LineItems/0/BasePrice/ConversionDate,LineItems/0/BasePrice/Currency/UniqueName,LineItems/0/Description.SupplierPartAuxiliaryID,LineItems/0/ExpectedTax.Component,LineItems/0/InspectionDate,LineItems/0/IsPriceModifiedByUser,LineItems/0/ChargeDetail.TaxAmount,LineItems/0/Description.ExtendedDescription,LineItems/0/SupplierLocation/UniqueName,LineItems/0/TaxDetail.TaxLocation,LineItems/0/TaxDetail.TaxAmount,LineItems/0/StartDate,LineItems/0/TaxDetail.ExemptDetail,LineItems/0/Description.Description,LineItems/0/IsRecurring,LineItems/0/NumberConfirmedSubstituted,LineItems/0/TaxDetail.AlternateTaxAmount,LineItems/0/Description.ExpirationDate,LineItems/0/Carrier,LineItems/0/Description.SupplierPartNumber,LineItems/0/TaxDetail.PaymentDate,LineItems/0/Order/UniqueName,LineItems/0/NumberConfirmedBackOrdered,LineItems/0/ChargeDetail.TaxCode,LineItems/0/Description.LeadTime,LineItems/0/ERPLineItemNumber,LineItems/0/Description.PriceBasisQuantityUOM,LineItems/0/Description.ItemNumber,LineItems/0/Category,LineItems/0/ChargeDetail.ChargeType,LineItems/0/NumberConfirmedRejected,LineItems/0/PaymentTerms,LineItems/0/TaxCode,LineItems/0/LineType/UniqueName,LineItems/0/Description.Price/AmountInReportingCurrency,LineItems/0/Description.Price/ApproxAmountInBaseCurrency,LineItems/0/Description.Price/Amount,LineItems/0/Description.Price/ConversionDate,LineItems/0/Description.Price/Currency/UniqueName,LineItems/0/TaxDetail.TaxPointDate,LineItems/0/OrderLineNumber,LineItems/0/WithholdingTaxAmount,LineItems/0/TaxDetail.Component,LineItems/0/BoughtFromPreferredSupplier,LineItems/0/Quantity,LineItems/0/TaxDetail.Purpose,LineItems/0/OrderInfo,LineItems/0/TaxDetail.IsTriangularTransaction,LineItems/0/ExpectedTax.TaxType,LineItems/0/TaxDetail.TriangularTransactionLawReference,LineItems/0/MALineItem/NumberInCollection
```

Comment: Do you mean that you need to reorder the CSV headers? Use `select-object` to put the object's fields in the right order before exporting to CSV: `$myData | select-object Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4 | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation $myFile`

Comment: Please edit your question. Format the json and shorten it, so we don't have to look at a wall of unformatted data. Also show what the desired output should be. _not the correct structure_ doesn't mean much..

Comment: @luke - No, when i use the above code, i get the header LineItems however value underneath comes as 'System.Object[]'

Comment: @Theo - Is there a way i can attach the expected output than to paste it in the question section?
Please let me know as I am new to stackoverflow as well

Comment: @Theo - I am looking at a way to handle the Lineitems tag in the Json since the JSON is deep nested, removing parts of it might lead to mismatch

Comment: @derekbaker783 - The below code does not help since the intent is to have a value for LineItems from the JSON. If we paste the JSON sample in an online JSON to CSV convertor tool, it provides LineItems the results as expected. The section under **"The expected sequence in the csv file for lineItems would be" ** are all the column names in the csv. –

Answer (score 0):

If you just want something that will prevent `System.Object[]` from appearing in the LineItems column, the code below will work.

Your expected output for the value in the LineItems column contains commas, so it will break formatting in your CSV (Unless your intent is to break up the line items across many rows and duplicate the other columns in each row, which would require a very different answer).

```
$data = (Get-Content -Path "$PSScriptRoot\input_data.json") | ConvertFrom-Json 

$data[0].LineItems = $data[0].LineItems | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 
$data[0].LineItems = Out-String -InputObject $data[0].LineItems

$data | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Set-Content "$PSScriptRoot\output_data.csv"
```

Comment: Yes the intent is to have a value for LineItems from the JSON. If we paste the JSON sample in an online JSON to CSV convertor tool, it provides LineItems the results as expected. 
The section under **"The expected sequence in the csv file for lineItems would be" ** are all the column names in the csv.

Comment: @justexecute, the converter is wrong. For instance, see this header: ```LineItems/0/CommodityCode/UniqueName```. UniqueName has no heirarchical relationship to CommodityCode in your JSON.